# Assigning A Point value to images to calculate A score

Tags: javafx

If I have the images of a standard 52 card deck and wanted to create a game in which 4 players randomly select a card from the deck and whoever has the highest value card wins. How would I assign values to the card images? I currently have a random number being assigned to pick the card for each player...

```
Button p1 = new Button("Player 1");

    p1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(52)+0;
            deckView.setImage(cards.get((n)%cards.size()));
            event.consume();
            p1.setDisable(true);
            Collections.shuffle(cards);

        }

    });
```

deck view is an object that displays the card above player one. As shown below: 
[OverView of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diQDq.png)

Do I need create 52 card objects and assign them values there? If I do that, do I need to find another way to find a random value using the objects of the cards instead of N? Here are the instructions if I did not explain clearly.

(The winner of the game is the player who won the most rounds. Each round, a player plays one card. The player with the highest value card wins the round. 2 is the lowest value and Ace is the highest value card. If multiples of the same card value is drawn, the suits determine the winner. Spades > Clubs > Diamonds > Hearts")

Comment: Do the card image names follow a certain pattern, e.g. `S10.png` for ten of spades and `HQ.png` for queen of hearts?

Comment: Yes each are labeled accordingly 10_of_spades.png or ace_of_hearts.png

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a list of the values / suits somewhere. If you put them into ascending order, you can quite easily create the cards in order of ascending value by using a nested loop for iterating over values and suits respectively, the outer loop being the one iterating the values.

As for drawing cards: You probably don't want repetition, so you should remove a card from the deck after drawing it.

```
public enum Suit {
    HEART("hearts"), SPADE("spades"), CLUB("clubs"), DIAMOND("diamonds");

    private final String imageString;

    Suit(String imageString) {
        this.imageString = imageString;
    }

    public String getImageString() {
        return imageString;
    }

}
```

```
public enum CardValue {
    TWO("2"),
    THREE("3"),
    FOUR("4"),
    FIVE("5"),
    SIX("6"),
    SEVEN("7"),
    EIGHT("8"),
    NINE("9"),
    TEN("10"),
    JACK("jack"),
    QUEEN("queen"),
    KING("king"),
    ACE("ace");

    private final String imageString;

    CardValue(String imageString) {
        this.imageString = imageString;
    }

    public String getImageString() {
        return imageString;
    }
}
```

```
public final class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    private final CardValue value;
    private final Suit suit;

    private final int cardValue;

    public Card(Suit suit, CardValue value) {
        if (suit == null || value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
        this.cardValue = value.ordinal() * 4 + suit.ordinal();
    }

    public CardValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        return cardValue - o.cardValue;
    }

    public Image createImage() {
        return new Image(value.getImageString() + "_of_" + suit.getImageString() + ".png");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return cardValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null
                && (obj instanceof Card)
                && (((Card)obj).cardValue == cardValue);
    }

}
```

```
private final Random random = new Random();
```

Create deck:

```
private final List<Card> cards;

{ 
    cards = new ArrayList<>(suits.length * values.length);
    Suit[] suits = Suit.values();
    CardValue[] values = CardValue.values();
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(suits.length * values.length);

    for (CardValue val : values) {
        for (Suit suit : suits) {
            cards.add(new Card(suit, val));
        }
    }
}
```

put all cards on a deck and shuffle

```
// create copy to avoid having to recreate all the cards when putting all cards back in the deck
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>(cards);
Collections.shuffle(deck, random);
```

Remove "topmost" card from the deck (in this case the last one in the list for efficiency):

```
Card card = deck.remove(deck.size() - 1);
```

Instead you could also not use `Collections.shuffle` on `deck` and instead remove a random card every time you draw a card:

```
Card card = deck.remove(random.nextInt(deck.size()));
```

The `Card` class provides a method for creating an image for it and comparing the card values.

Comment: So if the cards are already in a folder, each having its own file name, instead of creating the cards how would I assign values?

Comment: You could of course also take the file names, split them and compare the parts, but this is harder to implement. Furthermore if you include the images as resources in a jar, it's much more problematic to list them. For this reason I recommend creating the image urls based on the card values as shown in the answer.